# Simple website timing out when browsing locally

Tags: iis, localhost, windows-server-2012-r2

So Im new to the admin side of web hosting. I set up a windows server 2012 r2 box with IIS and while I can browse to the the default site in IIS from the local server I can not with my simple website I set up. It always gives me an time out error. I enabled as many logs as I could and I don't see any events getting written to them when I try to open them. Also I believe my bindings are ok because I'm taking a plural site course "IIS for developers" and I followed his directions exactly. I have been searching the new for hours trying to find an answer to no avail. Can someone point me in a direction so I'm not spinning my wheels?
Thanks

Comment: `404` isn't a "time out error", it's a "page not found error".  Whatever URL you're browsing to doesn't exist on that web server.

Comment: Sorry you are correct it is not a 404 but a timeout